# Waterline ORM assign the result of find to a variable

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I want to combine the results of 2 queries and then return them as one, like this:

```
test: async (req, res) => {
  const valOne = TableOne.find({ id: id })
      .exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.serverError(err);
        }
        return result;
      });
  const valTwo = TableTwo.find({ id: id })
      .exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.serverError(err);
        }
        return result;
      });
  const data = {
    keyOne: valOne,
    keyTwo: valTwo,
  };
  res.json(data);
}
```

I understand above code won't return because it's async. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much info you supply: node version, sails version, etc.

There are several approaches here:
1. Using promises
2. Using callback chaining
3. Using await/async

If you use sails 1.0 and node >= 8, your best bet is to use await/async, so your code should work like that:

```
test: async (req, res) => {
  let valOne, valTwo;

  try {
    valOne = await TableOne.find({ id: id });
    valTwo = await TableTwo.find({ id: id });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.serverError(err); //or res.badRequest(err);
  }

  const data = {
    keyOne: valOne,
    keyTwo: valTwo,
  };

  res.json(data);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked perfectly. i cant have exec there if i want to use await?

Comment: No, you can't mix await with exec, and you don't need to, await takes care of everything and you get your result in the variable, and in case of error you catch it in the catch block.

Comment: I would suggest you to try `[valOne, valTwo] = Promise.all(TableOne.find(), TableTwo.find()` also you can just attach `res.json` after that and before the `catch`